# GWTQuery load() replaces element

Tags: load, gwtquery

I am just getting started with GWTQuery, and am trying to wrap my head around the load() function. Consider:

```
    public void onModuleLoad() {
    SimplePanel sp = new SimplePanel();
    sp.getElement().setId("stuff");
    RootLayoutPanel root = RootLayoutPanel.get();
    root.add(sp);

    $("#stuff").load("/hello.html");
}
```

If I run the above, the empty `div` block for the SimplePanel element gets *replaced* with the contents of `hello.html`. In other words, it ends up in the `body` block, and the `div` disappears from the DOM. What I want is for the `div` block to *contain* `hello.html`. I worked around this by putting another temporary `SimplePanel` as the child of `div id="stuff"`, and calling `load()` on that. It works as desired. But I get the feeling I am missing something fundamental. Is there a way to do this without the throwaway `SimplePanel`?

Comment: I have run this code in my Project and it worked as expecetd. The div#stuff was not replaced with contents of hello.html. Do you still have that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your coded works ok, GQuery `load()` replaces the content of the element with the stuff gotten from the server.

The implementation of `load()` as you can see in [Ajax.java](https://github.com/manolo/gquery/blob/master/gwtquery-core/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/query/client/plugins/ajax/Ajax.java#L395), first clean the returned string removing `<html>` `<head>` `<body>` and `<script>` tags, then wrap the content into a `<div>`, and finally empty the content of the target panel (`$(#stuff)` in your case), and appends the new created `<div>`.

I've tested your code with last snapshot and with stable versions, what release are you using?